# Android Developer console stack trace

Tags: android, c++, google-play, stack-trace

I am getting following kind of stack trace for a live game on play store. - 
backtrace:

```
#00 pc 00395838 /data/app-lib/com.mycompany.game-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCAnimate::update(float)+432)
```

and

```
#00 pc 002d0028 /data/app/com.mycompany.game-1/lib/arm/libgame.so (MyClassName::myFunction(std::string, unsigned int, cocos2d::CCNode*)+984)
```

So what I need to know is how to find out the line (inside these functions) where the code is actually crashing. Also does these numbers at the end (+432 and +984) have any significance?

I am using `cocos2dx 2.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I found how to do this using `ndk-stack` from android NDK.

This tool is there in android NDK 7 and above. Pretty easy to use. There are two ways by which this function can be used

Do these in command prompt/terminal

1. With stack dump in a file:

   `$NDK/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi -dump stacktrace.txt`
2. stack trace as direct input from stdin

   `adb logcat | $NDK/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi`